# How do I make my website buttons shrink with the screen resolution?

Tags: html, css

My current website is having "issues" (not really a issue just bothers me) with my buttons hiding when the resolution changes to something smaller. Here is a gif so you understand it better. https://i.imgur.com/nlkJs5G.gifv. How can I fix it so it shrinks with the page so people can still click it on different screen resolutions?

Underneath is the html for the buttons. The .css for `fab` or `fa-steam-symbol` or `fa-discord` etc. is from https://fontawesome.com/ (if anyone is not familiar with it)

```css
 .awrapper{
    align-content:center;
    background-size:cover;
    display:flex;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:-webkit-flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    justify-content:center;
    min-height:100%;
    ms-flex-direction:row;
    ms-flex-line-pack:center;
    ms-flex-pack:center;
    ms-flex-wrap:wrap;
    webkit-align-content:center;
    webkit-flex-direction:row;
    webkit-flex-wrap:wrap;
    webkit-justify-content:center;
}
 .media{
    font-size:30px;
    text-align:center;
 padding-top:30px;
}
 .media>a{
    margin-right:80px;
    text-decoration:none;
    transition:color 0.5s ease;
}
 .media>a#vk{
    font-size:35px;
}
 .media>a:last-child{
    margin-right:0;
}
.animated{
    -webkit-animation-duration:2s;
    animation-duration:3s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;
    animation-fill-mode:both
 margin: 500px
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUpBig{
    from{
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,2000px,0);
        transform:translate3d(0,2000px,0)
    }
    to{
        opacity:1;
        -webkit-transform:none;
        transform:none
    }
}
@keyframes fadeInUpBig{
    from{
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,2000px,0);
        transform:translate3d(0,2000px,0)
    }
    to{
        opacity:1;
        -webkit-transform:none;
        transform:none
    }
}
.fadeInUpBig{
    -webkit-animation-name:fadeInUpBig;
    animation-name:fadeInUpBig
}
 .hvr-grow {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
    transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-property: transform;
    transition-property: transform;
}
 .hvr-grow:hover, .hvr-grow:focus, .hvr-grow:active {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<div class="awrapper">
    <div class="media animated fadeInUpBig" style="animation-delay: 5s;">
    <a href="BLNAK_LINK/Steam" target="_blank">
     <i class="fab fa-steam-symbol hvr-grow" title="Steam"></i>
    <a href="BLNAK_LINK/discord" target="_blank">
     <i class="fab fa-discord hvr-grow" title="Discord"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="BLNAK_LINK/hosting" target="_blank">
     <i class="fab fa-ioxhost hvr-grow" title="Hosting"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="BLNAK_LINK/TRADEOFFER" target="_blank">
     <i class="far fa-handshake hvr-grow" title="Tradelink"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="BLNAK_LINK/PLAYLIST" target="_blank">
    <i class="fas fa-music hvr-grow" title="Playlist"></i>
    </a>
    </div> 
    </div>
```

If I am missing anything or if you have questions please let me know and I will try to answer them.

Comment: Have you tried using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to adjust the size of your main container as the screen size changes?

Comment: @newcool you can make the button's row `position:fixed` to bottom to make them always visible when you resize screen. Other way use this in media query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help guys. You can check out the site and how it looks.

I added a new class called `unmoveable`

From

`<div class="media animated fadeInUpBig" style="animation-delay: 5s;">`

To

`<div class="media animated fadeInUpBig unmoveable">`

The css

```
.unmoveable {
    animation-delay: 5s;
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 100px;
}
```